# Malaysian Visa as a visitor in Singapore

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, malaysia

My friend is currently in Singapore as a tourist. What options does he have for applying for a Malaysian visa?

- The long term visa is available for Singapore Residents only. Special permission is required for non-residents.
- eNTRI and eVisa application is not allowed from Singapore.

Is there any other way to obtain a Malaysian visa from Singapore?

Comment: What country issued your friend's passport? And, use a VPN?

Comment: India. Also, tried VPN. They require itenary that starts and ends in India.